# Drag and drop custom image: at what size does the system automatically fade the outer edge?

Tags: windows, shell, drag-and-drop, windows-shell

I'm using IDragSourceHelper::InitializeFromBitmap() to create an image behind the mouse cursor during a drag & drop.  It works great, but for larger images, it seems that the system will do a transparency fade around the edges of the image.  That is reasonable, however I would like to keep the image size below that limit.  So how do I programmatically find the size limit that the system is using?

Answer (score 0):

The outer edges of drag image are blended out if the image width or height exceeds 300 pixels.

For example, here is a bitmap that has a width of 300 pixels.

[image]

And here is the same bitmap resized to a width of 301 pixels.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a source?  Seems like it would be more complicated than that.  300 pixels on a 4K monitor is a lot less than 300 on 1024x768